# postman password validation test with recaptcha response

Tags: postman, recaptcha, postman-testcase

Using postman I'm trying to test the password that inserted in the request by the user and check if its valid(6-14 characters and no spaces).I run post method test via postman with username and password in the body (RAW) and get a response with 403 forbidden and

```
{
"message": "RECAPCHA_FAILED"
}.
```

I'm guessing I need to use this `Recaptcha` response or something to proceed... How can I pass this captcha to the 'login' test to successfully login?

I've tried to send the username and password also via the `authorization` tab and getting 400 bad request...

Comment: You cannot and should not automate captcha. You can ask the developer to disable captcha in Dev/Test environment.